# Android volley ajax

Tags: php, android, ajax, android-volley

I want to get a response from a URL that has to do ajax requests to get and update the page without refreshing it.
My problem is when I want to receive its response with the volley library. In *onResponse* I just receive php code!!?

here is my code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());


        final String test= "MY URL";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, test,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        popup.dismiss();

                        Log.e("response", response );

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
popup.dismiss();
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

I tried with *Request.Method.POST* and *Request.Method.GET* but no difference.

**NOTE:**
I only can see the response of this URL when I am using chrome and *'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin'* extension is installed.

Comment: `receive php code` mean error is in your php code , request is not a success

Comment: php code is fine because I can get the response with chrome. Should I change the way I am getting the response in android?

Comment: see `response` must show you a valid text , so you need look for the issue , you can add the response value here as well